# Reset dlmopen namespace

Tags: c++, dlopen

I have a small program that loads 2 modules (X11, and my own):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int c, char* argv[])
{
    pid_t PID = c > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : -1;
    if (PID <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid PID\n");
        return -1;
    }

    const char* path = "/home/brandon/Desktop/mylib.so";

    void* x11 = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "libX11.so.6", RTLD_NOW);

    /*Lmid_t id = 0;
    dlinfo(dl, RTLD_DI_LMID, &id);
    dl = dlmopen(id, path, RTLD_LAZY);*/

    void* dl = dlopen(path, RTLD_LAZY);

    if (dl)
    {
        printf("Loading dll\n");

        void (*ptrace_info)(pid_t pid) = (decltype(ptrace_info))dlsym(dl, "ptrace_info");
        if (ptrace_info)
        {
            ptrace_info(PID);
        }

        dlclose(dl);
        printf("Unloaded\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I use `dlopen(path, RTLD_*)` my module fails to ptrace the specified pid. However, if I uncommented the code above that uses `dlmopen` everything works fine (even if I create a new namespace, it works)..

If I do not `dlmopen(.., X11, ..)`, it works fine. The only time it does NOT work is if I `dlmopen` anything and then try to `dlopen` something else.

Seeing as the only difference is the namespace, is there a way I can use `dlopen` after using `dlmopen`?

Comment: You say "my module fails to ptrace". Does that mean that `dlopen` succeeds, but the code inside `mylib.so` fails? In what way does it fail?

Comment: The `dlopen` itself fails completely. It doesn't get to the `printf("Loading dll\n")` line. I ended up giving up on this problem and I removed my use of `dlmopen` completely.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear what is _actually_ happening. Also, what is the output from `dlerror()` when `dlopen()` fails?